# How to get the access token from google?

Tags: cordova, youtube-api, ionic-framework, youtube-data-api

I am developing a mobile application using ionic framework in which the video has to be directly uploaded to the youtube channel, in order to achieve this i need to have an access token,i generated the access token from [oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and embedded in the code,it worked fine.
But the access token expires in an hour, So how can i retrieve the access token via java script after an hour from my mobile application.

any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got one that worked for me, check [code share](http://codeshare.io/1SLO2) for the code i used to make it work.
Due to security reasons its preferred not to generate the access token at the client side, instead of that generate it at the server side and fetch it from there,so for the server side i used php code to generate the access token and you can find the same [here](http://codeshare.io/i6JU5) by the way i have not added the code to re-fetch the token after an hour.